# In which cases iterative equations can be reduced to finite-difference equations?

Tags: functional-equations, dynamical-systems, finite-differences

In which cases iterative equations can be reduced to finite-difference equations and when they can't?

Answer (score 1):

In fact all iterative equations can be reduced to finite-difference equations by a suitable substitution, see http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe2315.pdf for details.

Comment: I do not think this applies it the equation has both iterations and derivatives, does it?